# ORACLE GROUP BY with Date does not group correctly

Tags: oracle, group-by, grouping

I try to group a given table by date to get a min and max date of member IDs. The result should display a time range from when to when a member was part of an OE.

my given table (excerpt):

```
ID  DATE                OE
11  2021-03-06 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-07 00:00:00 3879
11  2021-03-08 00:00:00 3879
11  2021-03-09 00:00:00 3879
11  2021-03-10 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-11 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-12 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-13 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-14 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-15 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-16 00:00:00 1344
11  2021-03-17 00:00:00 1344
11  2021-03-18 00:00:00 1344
11  2021-03-19 00:00:00 1344
11  2021-03-20 00:00:00 1344
11  2021-03-21 00:00:00 1344
11  2021-03-22 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-23 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-24 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-25 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-26 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-27 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-28 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-29 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-30 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-03-31 00:00:00 2926
11  2021-04-01 00:00:00 1549
11  2021-04-02 00:00:00 1549
11  2021-04-03 00:00:00 1549
11  2021-04-04 00:00:00 2926
```

My Select:

```
    select id, min(date) as mind, max(date) as maxd,OE
    from <table>
    group by id,oe
    order by mind desc;
```

The output should be something like this:

```
ID   | MIND                   | MAXD                   | OE
11     2021-04-04 00:00:00      2021-04-04 00:00:00      2926
11     2021-04-01 00:00:00      2021-04-03 00:00:00      1549
11     2021-03-22 00:00:00      2021-03-31 00:00:00      2926
11     2021-03-16 00:00:00      2021-03-21 00:00:00      1344
11     2021-03-10 00:00:00      2021-03-15 00:00:00      2926
11     2021-03-07 00:00:00      2021-03-09 00:00:00      3879
11     2021-03-06 00:00:00      2021-03-06 00:00:00      2926
```

But it is like this:

```
ID   | MIND                   | MAXD                   | OE
11     2021-04-01 00:00:00      2021-04-03 00:00:00      1549
11     2021-03-16 00:00:00      2021-03-21 00:00:00      1344
11     2021-03-07 00:00:00      2021-03-09 00:00:00      3879
11     2021-03-06 00:00:00      2021-04-04 00:00:00      2926
```

The result should display a time range from when to when a member was part of an OE. Even if I add some other IDs (which I obviously have) it does not show the timeline of OE changes in correct order.

Any help highly appreciated!

TIA,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trick called [`tabibitosan`](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) to do this kind of grouping:

```
SELECT id,
       MIN(dt) AS mind,
       MAX(dt) AS maxd,
       oe
FROM   (SELECT id,
               dt,
               oe,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY dt) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, oe ORDER BY dt) grp
        FROM   your_table)
GROUP  BY id,
          oe,
          grp
ORDER  BY mind DESC;
```

See [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Orl_m1_t) for results

This works by assigning row numbers across the whole set of data (in this case, it's across each id), and then finding the row numbers across the subsets of data (i.e. across each id and oe), and then subtracting one from the other to form a number you can group by. Consecutive rows get the same group number, but every time there's a non-consecutive row, the group number will change.

Comment: I like this approach... :-) and it is quick! First run with 74million lines took 1m20s, with the /*+ PARALLEL */ hint it took under one minute to complete! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY "DATE"
  MEASURES
    FIRST(oe)     AS oe,
    FIRST("DATE") AS mind,
    LAST("DATE")  AS maxd
  PATTERN (same_oe+)
  DEFINE
    same_oe AS oe = FIRST(oe)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, "DATE", OE) AS
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-06', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-07', 3879 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-08', 3879 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-09', 3879 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-10', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-11', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-12', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-13', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-14', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-15', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-16', 1344 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-17', 1344 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-18', 1344 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-19', 1344 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-20', 1344 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-21', 1344 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-22', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-23', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-24', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-25', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-26', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-27', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-28', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-29', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-30', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-03-31', 2926 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-04-01', 1549 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-04-02', 1549 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-04-03', 1549 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2021-04-04', 2926 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | OE | MIND | MAXD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2926 | 2021-03-06 00:00:00 | 2021-03-06 00:00:00 |
| 11 | 3879 | 2021-03-07 00:00:00 | 2021-03-09 00:00:00 |
| 11 | 2926 | 2021-03-10 00:00:00 | 2021-03-15 00:00:00 |
| 11 | 1344 | 2021-03-16 00:00:00 | 2021-03-21 00:00:00 |
| 11 | 2926 | 2021-03-22 00:00:00 | 2021-03-31 00:00:00 |
| 11 | 1549 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 2021-04-03 00:00:00 |
| 11 | 2926 | 2021-04-04 00:00:00 | 2021-04-04 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MR2oDP_X)

Comment: Awsome! This piece of code does its job very nice. But I'd rather prefer partitioning from the beginning rather than a row-by-row-matching - just for performance reasons. Your example takes ~3.5mins to complete on a 74million lines table (even with parallelism) whilst the below one completes under one minute. Anyway - thank you so much for your hard work! Highly appreciated!